# React Native measure Text height before render

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a Flatlist and I need to measure the heights of items to scroll. I've tried [react-native-text-size](https://github.com/aMarCruz/react-native-text-size) measure function, but it overestimates the number of lines, but it works perfectly on IOS. I would like to ask if there are any solutions to measure the height before render.

Comment: No component no height. May I ask why do you need to know height of items in Flatlist? In case of ScrollView I agree, we don't have index and we need to calculate items height.

Comment: @M.N. Yeah unfortunately we have a flatlist and want to scroll to some items which are not rendered, so we need `getItemLayout` which needs components size

Comment: I can't see any any opportunity scroll to unrenered component. Maybe I'm wrong. Why don't you use preloader until items rendered or if you know number of items, you can render some dummy blur components.

Comment: @M.N. I fixed it eventually with `onScrollFailed` and without specifying `getItemLayout`